My DQN does not show a trend, But TD3 and DDPG show a trend, why？
I use multi-head DQN,but my does not show a trend.  DDQN does not show a trend, too.
DQN image
But TD3 and DDPG show a trend.
TD3 and DDPG images
My code as follow: https://www.kaggle.com/code/airenchan/dqn-code
I have tried many approaches, including modifying the rewards, changing the number of training iterations, and adjusting the learning process, but none of these changes seem to make a difference.

My code as follow: https://www.kaggle.com/code/airenchan/dqn-code
